# How to save results in 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a Python code that creates a 2-dimensional array, processes and saves the results in the array like:

```
dimension = [32, 64]
partition = [10, 20, 30, 40]

row = len(dimension)
column = len(partition)

qpi_partition = [[0 for x in range(column)] for y in range(row)]

for d in dimension:
   for i, j in enumerate(qpi_partition):
      *do_process*
      for p in partition:
         *result = do_process*
         qpi_partition[i].append(result)
```

The output is:

```
[[0,  0,  0,  0,  0.25,  0.32,  0.54,  0.64,  0.78,  0.12,  0.55,  0.21],
[0,  0,  0,  0,  0.25,  0.32,  0.54,  0.64,  0.78,  0.12,  0.55,  0.21]]
```

But actually, what I want is something like this, in which each dimension has a four partitions results like:

```
[[0.25,  0.32,  0.54,  0.64], 
[0.78,  0.12,  0.55,  0.21]]
```

My question is:

(1) how can I create a 2-dimensional array and populate it with results (without initializes zeros in it)

(2) which loop did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: To me it's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @timgeb, I'd like to know why did all the results are saved in each row, in which what I want is only 4 results (partition) for each row (dimension)

Answer (score 1):

### Eliminating the superfluous 0's

Python's `[]` is not an array; it's a list. It is dynamically sized.

The `append` function does exactly what it says; it extends the list to add the new item.

So you're initializing your inner lists with 0's, then *extending* them to add your results. Either use indexing to *overwrite* the 0's, or don't initialize your lists that way (just create empty lists).

### Not duplicating your results in each row

It's not entirely clear from your question, but it looks like you want each entry `(r,c)` in your `qpi_partition` matrix to correspond to the result of some function `f(x,y)`, where `x` is `dimension[r]` and `y` is `partition[c]`. In other words, you're taking each pair of elements from `dimension` and `partition`, computing some function on that pair, and storing it in your result structure.

To do this, you should have one loop per dimension in your result structure, and since your inputs are one-dimensional, your binary-function pairwise mapping will result in a two-dimensional structure (which, based on the title, you already realize, even if you wouldn't have phrased it that way). But you have *three* loops!

The core problem, I think, is that you're iterating over your result structure (`qpi_partition`) *and* your input vectors. Really, you should iterate over *either* your inputs *or* your outputs.

Here's a version mapping only over inputs:

```
qpi_partition = [[0 for x in range(len(partition))] for y in range(len(dimension))]

for d, r in enumerate(dimension):
    for p, c in enumerate(partition):
        result = # Calculate result....
        qpi_partition[r][c]  = result
```

Comment: Caution, nitpick: "Python doesn't natively have arrays" <- instances of `bytes` are considered arrays according to their docstring.

Comment: @Kyle Strand, do you mean create empty array like `qpi_partition = []`?

Comment: @Lucy Not exactly, because then you'd need to add the inner lists. It makes sense to initialize it with *empty* inner lists: `[[] for y in range(row)]`

Comment: @timgeb Interesting--I haven't used Python 3 much, so I didn't realize `bytes` (which wasn't in 2) is considered an array. Fixed.

Comment: @Kyle Strand, thanks! the beginning zeros have been eliminated.

Now I've got:

`dim_1   0.25  0.32  0.54  0.64  0.78  0.12  0.55  0.21` and `dim_2   0.25  0.32  0.54  0.64  0.78  0.12  0.55  0.21`

but did I used `enumerate()` wrongly?

Comment: @Lucy There's no reason to use `enumerate` unless you intend to use the values *and* the indices. You could use the inner-list references directly: `for inner in qpi_partition: ... inner.append(result)`; or, keeping your indexing approach,  just `for i in range(len(qpi_partition)): ... qpi_partition[i].append(result)`.

Comment: @Kyle Strand thanks for this. However, this still gives me the above output (in my question only without the zeros), while what I need the above third box `dim_1   0.25  0.32  0.54  0.64 
dim_2   0.78  0.12  0.55  0.21`

Comment: I maybe using the append wrongly, I'm so confuse now and don't know which loop is wrong

Comment: @Lucy To be honest it's not clear from your code what you're trying to do, or where the numbers are coming from. It looks like you probably shouldn't have so many `for` loops--perhaps your iteration over `dimension` is supposed to be synchronized with the corresponding result elements of `qpi_partition`?

Comment: @Kyle Strand, I'm sorry for making it more confusing. 

The numbers are the results of the processes. There are supposed to be only 4 results (or partitions) for each dimension. I'd like to store the results based on its corresponding dimension (row). So, in the end, it should have only 2 rows (2 dimensions) in which each row has 4 partitions (4 values/columns).

Comment: @Lucy Okay, I think I understand. Note that "dimension" seems to be completely the wrong variable name here, though, since a row is not a "dimension" in the standard sense.

Comment: @Lucy I've added a section that should address your second question.

Comment: @KyleStrand, thanks so much for your answer. Really appreciate it.